# Regex : Reforming a url path if a particular string pattern is found in the path

Tags: regex, redirect, aws-elb

I am not much experienced using regex and fighting to solve the problem:
I have a url like below:

> http://example.com/**ja-JP**/blog/12345

I want to redirect the above url to below url :

> http://**jp**.example.com/**ja**/blog/12345

Moreover I want to do the redirect using aws ALB redirection rule.
And I will have to do the same URL redirection with different country-locale pattern.
for example en-BZ, en-CA.

I need help how to capture the language-Country part and reform the source URL?

Answer (score 0):

This is the regexp for matching language and country:

```
\/(?<lang>[a-z]{2})-(?<country>[A-Z]{2})\/
```

[here is the example](https://regex101.com/r/H9bvxS/1)

> [a-z] for lowercase letter, [a-z]{2} for two lowercase letters, (?<lang>[a-z]{2}) make it a group and name it 'lang', and then a dash '-', and two uppercase letters group and name it 'country', and is contained in two '/'

Since I don't know what's your developing language, say it's PHP, then:

```
preg_match('/\/(?<lang>[a-z]{2})-(?<country>[A-Z]{2})\//' ,$url, $matches);
// $matches['lang']='ja' $matches['country']='JP'

$url = preg_replace('/\/(?<lang>[a-z]{2})-(?<country>[A-Z]{2})\//', '/'.$matches['lang'].'/', $url);
// $url = 'https://example.com/ja/blog/12345'

$url = preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/)/', '$1'.$matches['country'].'.', $url);
// $url = 'https://JP.example.com/ja/blog/12345'
```

> (https?://) matches "http://" or "https://"

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript following `Regular expressions` can be helpful:

```js
/(example.com\/[a-z]{2,})-([a-z]{2,})/i
```

Below are the working examples:

```js
'http://example.com/ja-JP/blog/12345'.replace(/(example.com\/[a-z]{2,})-([a-z]{2,})/i, '$2.$1');
// Outputs "http://JP.example.com/ja/blog/12345"

'http://example.com/en-BZ/blog/12345'.replace(/(example.com\/[a-z]{2,})-([a-z]{2,})/i, '$2.$1');
// Outputs "http://BZ.example.com/en/blog/12345"
```